# correct signature to use in getmethod on class with multiple overloaded generic methods requiring delegate argument

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, delegates, methodinfo

Following an answer fulfilling the question in part here is some additional information to hopefully solve the points still at issue

**Start edit**

`var curEntityPI = ctx.GetType().GetProperties().Where(pr => pr.Name == "Client").First();
                Type curEntityType = curEntityPI.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();
                Type[] typeArgs = { curEntityType };
                Type propertyManagerType = generic.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
                var propertyManager = Activator.CreateInstance(propertyManagerType, new object[] {});`

with this in mind i can't use the closeMethod.Invoke in the same way displayed in the first answer and it is the Func and return body that I don't know how to put in place when invoking

**End edit**

What should the method signature look like to reflection, I'm trying to invoke the equivalent of this

```
DynamicPropertyManager<ThreeColumns>.CreateProperty<ThreeColumns, string>(
     "Four",
     t => "Four",
     null
  ));
```

on this class found here http://putridparrot.com/blog/dynamically-extending-an-objects-properties-using-typedescriptor/

1. But I'm trying to do it using reflection. What I'm struggling with
   the most is getting the correct method overload.
2. I have to be honest though I'm also not totally sure how to supply the correct argument for the lambda bit through reflection
   either.

I was going to try this in part but don't know what the func bit
    would look like when doing MakeGenericMethod

```
Func<string> funcArg = () => { return "Four"; };
```

`object[] args = { fieldOrPropertyName , funcArg, null }`;

The class contents from the link above are included for reference.

```
public class DynamicPropertyManager<TTarget> : IDisposable
{
    private readonly DynamicTypeDescriptionProvider provider;
    private readonly TTarget target;

    public DynamicPropertyManager()
    {
        Type type = typeof(TTarget);

        provider = new DynamicTypeDescriptionProvider(type);
        TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(provider, type);
    }

    public DynamicPropertyManager(TTarget target)
    {
        this.target = target;

        provider = new DynamicTypeDescriptionProvider(typeof(TTarget));
        TypeDescriptor.AddProvider(provider, target);
    }

    public IList<PropertyDescriptor> Properties
    {
        get { return provider.Properties; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(target, null))
        {
            TypeDescriptor.RemoveProvider(provider, typeof(TTarget));
        }
        else
        {
            TypeDescriptor.RemoveProvider(provider, target);
        }
    }

    public static DynamicPropertyDescriptor<TTargetType, TPropertyType>
       CreateProperty<TTargetType, TPropertyType>(
           string displayName,
           Func<TTargetType, TPropertyType> getter,
           Action<TTargetType, TPropertyType> setter,
           Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return new DynamicPropertyDescriptor<TTargetType, TPropertyType>(
           displayName, getter, setter, attributes);
    }

    public static DynamicPropertyDescriptor<TTargetType, TPropertyType>
       CreateProperty1<TTargetType, TPropertyType>(
          string displayName,
          Func<TTargetType, TPropertyType> getHandler,
          Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return new DynamicPropertyDescriptor<TTargetType, TPropertyType>(
           displayName, getHandler, (t, p) => { }, attributes);
    }

    public static DynamicPropertyDescriptor<TTargetType, TPropertyType>
       CreateProperty<TTargetType, TPropertyType>(
          string displayName,
          Func<TTargetType, TPropertyType> getHandler,
          Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return new DynamicPropertyDescriptor<TTargetType, TPropertyType>(
           displayName, getHandler, (t, p) => { }, attributes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflection and generics are working very well together, but how to approach a specific goal is very context dependant, because of possibly closed, open and partially closed types and methods. Nonetheless often it is easy to get what you are looking for by using Linq. Have a look:

```
// get type from somewhere
var compileTimeUnknownType = Type.GetType("ThreeColumns");

if (compileTimeUnknownType == null)
    throw new ArgumentException("compileTimeUnknownType");

var managerType = typeof (DynamicPropertyManager<>).MakeGenericType(compileTimeUnknownType);

var createPropertyMethod = managerType.GetMethods().Single(x =>
{
    var p = x.GetParameters();
    var g = x.GetGenericArguments();
    return x.Name == "CreateProperty" &&
            p.Length == 3 &&
            g.Length == 2 &&
            p[0].ParameterType == typeof (string) &&
            p[1].ParameterType == typeof (Func<,>).MakeGenericType(g) &&
            p[2].ParameterType == typeof (Attribute[]);
});

var closedMethod = createPropertyMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] {compileTimeUnknownType, typeof (string)});

var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(compileTimeUnknownType, "arg");
var lambda =
    Expression.Lambda(typeof (Func<,>).MakeGenericType(new[] {compileTimeUnknownType, typeof (string)}),
        Expression.Constant("Four"), new List<ParameterExpression>() {paramExpr}).Compile();

var ret = closedMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] {"Four", lambda, null});
```

Comment: Hi thanks massively for your reply I think the createPropertyMethod will work great, but the problem I have is that the reason I am using reflection is that the ThreeColumns class is unknown to me until runtime. In my case the class I am attaching a property to is actually another generic class which I have got via reflection and then instantiated the propertymanager instance with the class type see edit

Comment: I have modified the code, now the `ThreeColumns` type is not compile time referenced anymore.

Comment: Thanks so very much for looking at this. I'll give it a go and then accept and vote up.your answer. You really have been a lifesaver

Comment: It works! exactly as expected. I spent most of the afternoon looking to complete it on my own, I got the first generic bits & use of Expression.Constant but not the paramExpr bit. Its so fustrating getting stuck on something fundamental to what I'm trying to do. Thanks so much.